# BCrypt issues with checking password against database in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I am relatively new to ruby and rails so sorry if any of my code is a little messy or doesn't follow general conventions.  Any comments on that are welcomed.

I'm trying to make a user/password authentication system using BCrypt but when I go to check the password against the one thats been hashed it always fails.

**User.rb**

```
#encryption of password
before_save :encrypt_password
after_save :clear_password

def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_hash = Password.create(password)
  end
end

def clear_password
  self.password = nil
end

#authentication
def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
  if EMAIL_REGEX.match(username_or_email)
    user = User.find_by_email(username_or_email)
  else
    user = User.find_by_username(username_or_email)
  end
  if user && user.password_hash == login_password
    return user
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new( user_params )
  if @user.save 
    flash[:notice] = "You've signed up successfully"
    flash[:color] = "valid"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
  end
  render "new"
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
  def login_attempt
    authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email], params[:login_password])
    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      @current_user = authorized_user
      logger.debug "User has been authorized"
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"
      redirect_to(:action => 'home')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
      render "login"
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I _think_ you just need to change `if user && user.password_hash == login_password` to `if user && BCrypt.Password.new(user.password_hash) == login_password`. I don’t know if you can get Rails to automatically create a `BCrypt::Password` from the raw hash.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet the issue is with comparing stored password's *hash* with plain password *string*:

```
def login_attempt
    authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email], params[:login_password])
```

and

```
def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
  ...
  if user && user.password_hash == login_password
  #          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

<strike>You'd probably need to fix the comparison with `user.password_hash == Password.new(login_password)`</strike> .
You'd need just make sure if `login_password` does not contain some trailing characters like newline or if `self.password_hash` does not get altered in the meantime.

Also noticed possible typo in `clear_password` method - `self.password = nil` instead of `self.password_hash = nil`.

As a side note, I'd leave authentication to some mature module like [Devise](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/) (warning: requires javascript enabled)

Comment: Because of the way the BCrypt `Password` class redefines the `==` method, the comparison `user.password_hash == login_password` actually makes sense.

Comment: @WallyAltman Oh, you are right. Comparison operator converts a parameter to hash internally.

Comment: The `clear_password` method clears the password that was saved to memory as a variable from the form. At least, I think thats what it was intended to do.  It runs after the `User.save` command runs.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a different way to do it using BCrypt still.  Rails has a built in `has_secure_password` that works if the column in the users table is called `password_digest`.  It works like this:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
  def login_attempt
    if EMAIL_REGEX.match(params[:username_or_email])
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:username_or_email])
    else
      user = User.find_by_username(params[:username_or_email])
    end

    authorized_user = user.authenticate(params[:login_password])

    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      @current_user = authorized_user
      redirect_to(:action => 'home')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
      render "login"
    end
  end
```

and in the **user.rb** class file there has to be a line of code that just says:

```
has_secure_password
```